# Applescript | Extracting highest integer and create numbers from 0 to highest integer

Tags: applescript, filtering

I have a script returning the following results:

https://XY.com/shop/General-Mad-Dog-Mattis-For-PrN

https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=29

https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=26

Now i need to find the highest integer (in this case &p=29) and create new strings from https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=0 up to the highest found integer in this case https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=29

So far i managed to extract the URL's needed with the following code:

```
set AllUrls to {"https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=26", "https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=29", "https://XY.com/shop/General-Mad-Dog-Mattis-For-PrN"}

-- FILTER PAGING URLS
set PagingFilter to "&p="
set PagingUrls to {}
repeat with i from 1 to length of AllUrls
    if item i of AllUrls contains PagingFilter then

        set end of PagingUrls to item i of AllUrls
    end if
end repeat
PagingUrls -- returns {"https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=26", "https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=29"}
```

And a small Script to extract the last 2 Digits from the URLs:

```
set alphabet to "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set myURLs to {"https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=26", "https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=29"}
set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to ¬
    {space} & characters of the alphabet & {".", "_"}
set a to text items of myURLs as text

get last word of a --> returns "21"


set numlist to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count of words in a

    set this_item to word i of a
    try
        set this_item to this_item as number
        set the end of numlist to this_item

    end try

end repeat
numlist -- returns {26, 29}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another approach.

It splits the URLs with `text item delimiters` by delimiter `&p=`. If the delimiter exists, get the integer (the right side of the delimiter) and save it as `maxValue` if the current value is higher than the previous value.

Then use a loop to create the list of page URLs

```
set AllUrls to {"https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=26", "https://XY.com/search?q=mad%20dog&p=29", "https://XY.com/shop/General-Mad-Dog-Mattis-For-PrN"}

set maxValue to 0
set baseURL to ""
set TID to text item delimiters
set text item delimiters to "&p="
repeat with anURL in AllUrls
    set textItems to text items of anURL
    if (count textItems) is 2 then
        set currentValue to item 2 of textItems as integer
        if currentValue > maxValue then set maxValue to currentValue
        set baseURL to item 1 of textItems & "&p="
    end if
end repeat
set text item delimiters to TID
set pageURLs to {}
repeat with i from 0 to maxValue
    set end of pageURLs to baseURL & i
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian! Am i wrong or does this "just" return the URL with the highest integer? Or should it return a list of urls from integer 0 to maxValue?

Comment: The result (all page URLs as a list) is in the variable `pageURLs`

Comment: Ah, my fault :) i though ti should when looking at the script, just forgot to output the correct variable :) Thanks a million, way easier then my approach!